# Question about nested intervals - real analysis I

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the theorem of the nested intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. I have to give an example of a nested sequence $(I_n)$ of closed intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ such that the intersection of all the closed intervals = empty set.

I used the nested interval $[n,+\infty[$ and my proof goes as follows:
Suppose that the intersection of all these intervals is not equal to the empty set. Then, there exists an element $x$ in the intersection of all these intervals. Thus, $x > n$ for all $n$ of the natural numbers. But according to the archimedian property of the $\mathbb{R}$ there exists an element m of the natural numbers such that $x < m$. So we have a contradiction, thus the intersection is empty.

I have a question about this proof:

- Is the interval $[n,+\infty[$ a closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$? I assume it is because of the fact that the complement is open.

Comment: I've edited in some MathJax. You can find a tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/10513).

Comment: Yes: $[n, + \infty [$ is a closed interval. Your proof is fine, it's a standard example.

Comment: Thanks for editing/commenting.